# Assign smaller matrix to larger matrix (centered about an element in the larger matrix)?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a 1920x1080 image matrix. I also have a 3x3 matrix kernel. I want to assign the kernel to values of the image centered at any valid pixel location (ii, jj).

```
kernel(1, 1) = image(ii-1, jj-1);
kernel(1, 2) = image(ii-1, jj  );
kernel(1, 3) = image(ii-1, jj+1);
kernel(2, 1) = image(ii  , jj-1);
kernel(2, 2) = image(ii  , jj  );
...
kernel(3, 3) = image(ii+1, jj+1);
```

Is there a shortcut to do this besides loops?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do that assignment for a given `(ii,jj)`, you could do it in a single statement:

```
kernel = image(ii-1:ii+1, jj-1:jj+1);
```